# TiffBitmapEncoder not saving in color

Tags: c#, tiff

Our users needed the ability to change images (rotate\insert scan between pages etc) so I wrote an app that allows them to load a Tiff image and edit as needed.

The problem I have is that when the image is saved it is saved as black and white and not in color. The loaded image displays in color no problem so it seems that it is the saving that is causing the issue.

This is the code I am using to save the Tiff image from an array of BitmapSource:

```
//create encoder
TiffBitmapEncoder tiffEncoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
tiffEncoder.Compression = TiffCompressOption.Ccitt4; 

//loop through images and create frames
foreach (BitmapSource src in bitmapList)
{
    BitmapFrame bmFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(src);
    tiffEncoder.Frames.Add(bmFrame);
}

//create stream to write file
FileStream fStream = null;
try
{
    fStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
    //Save Tiff image to disc
    tiffEncoder.Save(fStream);
}
finally
{
    if (fStream != null)
    {
         fStream.Close();
    }
}
```

When I look at the properties of the original file it has a bit depth of 24 but the newly saved image has a bit depth of 1 (black and white?), is this the problem?

I am new to working with Tiffs so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if you need any other info.

Tx

Comment: It's probably due to the `TiffCompressOption.Ccitt4` compression used. The CCITT compressions are intended for fax documents, and only supports black/white images. Try using a more general purpose compression, like LZW or Deflate.

Comment: Thanks dude, worked 100%. Do you want to create an answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: Great! Posted as answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images are probably converted to black/white, because of the `TiffCompressOption.Ccitt4` compression  in use. The CCITT compressions are intended for fax documents, and only supports black/white images.

Instead, use a more general purpose compression, like LZW or Deflate. This will let the image data pass unchanged as 24 or 32 bit color data.